# GL_POLYGON not filled properly?

Tags: opengl, rendering

[image]

Why are those lines appearing in my shape?

I'm initializing OpenGL like this:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And drawing the shape like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-5, -5); // bottom left
    glVertex2f(5, -5); // bottom right...
    glVertex2f(6, 0);
    glVertex2f(5, 5);
    glVertex2f(-5, 5);
glEnd();
```

Doesn't matter if it's clockwise or CCW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH is an antiquated and slow method of polygon anti-aliasing.  It also results in the problem you see above.

Using the Multisample buffer extension is the best way to perform fast anti-aliasing on modern machines.  Read more [here.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multisample.txt)

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out how to enable multisampling, but I got it to work. This works well :) Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I think disabling GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH would fix that, but you'd lose the antialiasing. FSAA would work as an alternative, but it'd be slower.

Edit: looking around, there are a lot of examples out there using `glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE );`

Comment: Disabling GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH did indeed fix it. The latter solution makes it disappear altogether though. Is there no happy median?

Comment: I want to note that the blend mode mentioned here is the correct answer. GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH is meant to be used with `glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE );` which only exists to remove these inner lines